# Difference between canonical and base tag

Tags: seo, redirects, search-engine-indexing, canonical-url, no-www

I am a little bit confused regarding the usage of canonical tags and base tags.

I have placed canonical tag (`rel="canonical"`) on my website because of my website opening with no-www.  I have reviewed my website through SEO doctor add-ons which is showing that my website is not indexable in search engine. Can anyone can explain this?

Answer (score 5):

### Canonical Tag

The canonical tag tells search engines what the URL of the *current* page should be.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/mypage.html" />
```

tells search engines that the current page should be indexed at `http://www.example.com/mypage.html` even if they crawl it at `http://example.com/mypage.html`

### Base Tag

The base tag tells all browsers how the URLs of every relative link in the page should start.

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/">
```

tells browsers (and crawlers) to open any relative links in such a way that they start with `http://www.example.com/`.  So a link to `/myotherpage.html` would go to `http://www.example.com/myotherpage.html`, even if that link were found on `http://example.com/mypage.html`

---

Without examining your website itself, I can't tell you why your site isn't able to be indexed.  If you add a comment with a link to it, we can take a look at it.  Using canonical tags and base tags should not prevent your site from being indexed if you used them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`rel="canonical"` solution is frequently used between two pages with same content (not for an entire website). Explanations [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394).

[Base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) is different and used to specify default URL for all relative URLs in the page.

However, keep available two versions of your website (`www` and `no-www` versions) can be hasardous because it generates duplicate content. And Google doesn't like duplicate content, that's why it's good seo pratice to redirect www to no-www or the opposite.

If you use [Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/) as web server, you can create *[.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess)* file in root of your domain (if it doesn't already exist) and add these lines to redirect ([301 redirect](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633)) `www` to `no-www`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Of course, you replace *example.com* by your website URL.

You also can choose the opposite (redirect from `no-www` to `www`) if you prefer. No matter for seo if you choose one or other solution.

What is important is to implement 301 redirect solution unlike `rel="canonical"` solution to do this.